# Swiffy Extending Flash File Beyond 30 Second Limit

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

I am converting a Flash ad which runs for 10 seconds into HTML5, using Google Swiffy converter.

When the converison is made, the ad loops 3 times, and seems to slightly extend the overall length past the 30 second limit of Google Display Ads.

Is there a way I can stop the ad from being looped or alternatively, shorten then ad run time by slightly speeding up the ads?

Cheers,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the ad from being looped, you can put a `stop()` ActionScript snippet at the end of the timeline and the ad should just stop looping.

To speed up the ad - the simplest, easiest way would be to increase the fps of the ad itself in Flash, and then convert it again using Swiffy.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up working out that I could alter the number of loops on the file too, which ended up being easier. I managed to turn the loop to 2 and keep it below 30 seconds. Thanks mate!